# proguard hell - can't find referenced class

Tags: android, proguard

So, I'm *TRYING* to release some software but Proguard is giving me a headache.

When I try to export using proguard I'm getting lots of warning ie "can't find referenced class"

For example:

```
[2011-08-07 17:44:37 - GAME] Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
[2011-08-07 17:44:37 - GAME] Warning: there were 52 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2011-08-07 17:44:37 - GAME]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'),
[2011-08-07 17:44:37 - GAME]          or perhaps the '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' option.
[2011-08-07 17:44:37 - GAME] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[
```

The warnings seem to related to simpleframework, so in my proguard config file I've added the following:

```
-libraryjars pathtoprojecttolibs\simple-xml-2.4.jar
```

Where `pathtoprojecttolibs` is the path to jars which are referenced by my project.

This makes NO difference.

If simpleframework references javax can I tell proguard to ignore this too??

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using proguard just to do treeshaking? If so, have you checked you file size without using it? You can get superwierd bugs when proguard throws out something that is accessed using reflection for instance which you won't find until it breaks runtime so be really, really sure you need it.

Comment: I was really only using it to try to protect the code being nicked as easily? Do you think its worth it?

Comment: @ListenToRick Proguard is perfectly fine, if it's run with the proper configs and your resultant app tested properly. I'm pretty sure Google even recommends its use. Google provides a lot of guides/examples for using Proguard with Android apps.

Comment: Proguard is a good tool but google recommending it is probably at least as much because of a rather wierd size limitation in the dex-format as anything else. (See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7147)

Comment: @alun, that's not the reason. Those of us who don't want our apps reverse engineered, or who are using licensing to 'try' to prevent piracy should use an obfuscation tool such as this to make it harder for would be hackers. Making your application take less space is also a benefit for the end user, and there are also optimizations made by these tools as well... yet another benefit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error occurs because the libs you use depend on other libs which are not realy used, but Proguard is looking for them. 
Add your **-dontwarn** lines to your **proguard-rules.pro** file in your Android project to disable this warnings.

[image]

You can find which dependencies you need to add to your proguard-rules.pro in the stacktrace of your error.

Answer (score 128):

`org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader` in your code refers to `javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent`. The latter class is part of the Java runtime (`rt.jar`) but not part of the Android runtime (`android.jar`), so ProGuard warns that something might be broken. If you're sure that your application works anyway, you can specify

```
-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**
```

ProGuard hell?

Comment: That did not fix it for me, however this did `-dontwarn javax.xml.**`

Comment: Adding `-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: For those running into similar warnings with **Guava**, [check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120338/proguard-configuration-for-guava-with-obfuscation-and-optimization/20935044#20935044).

Comment: I got additional warnings about eg javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory, so i used `-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.**`

Comment: How can I set `-dontwarn` sing the GUI?

Comment: Its weird I still encountered this problem in 2018, I am not sure what I missed but is this solution still apply in 2018 without some drawbacks?

Answer (score 9):

In my case the root cause was [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/505/). Those warnings you can just skip with :

```
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.xml.stream.**
```

The [original answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27274020/3825406)

Answer (score 3):

You should include this in your Proguard config:

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
```

Comment: Well, it did for me at the time...~4 years ago...things may have changed since then :) Seemed to have worked for at least 2 other people anyway.

Comment: The default [proguard-android.txt](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/android-4.1.2_r2/files/proguard-android.txt) already has this line.

Comment: @Ultimecia that commit is from 2013, this post was made in 2011

Answer (score 3):

My Magic key that solved my hours of searching: Add this to progruard-android.txt

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Reading that warning it would seem the library you are trying to use has a dependancy on javax.xml.stream.events. I don't think that namespace is actually included in android at all. (See [Package Index](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)).

Try deploying it to the emulator without using proguard and see if it works. My guess would be no if that warning is accurate.

Comment: Hi, if it is working in emulator without the proguard, it means the warnings are inaccurate? I am trying to figure out why I had these kind of similar warnings. I don't want to just suppress the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an edge case but in my case I had to completely wipe the build folder on my Jenkins proguard tried to work with old code which was not there any more - just in case anybody has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I haven't changed anything and warning started to show. The problem was with broken gradle caches. Check my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48582992/1550077). I share with this because it took my 2 hours to find the problem :]

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `proguard-rules.pro` file in the gradle scripts directory:

```
-dontwarn package.class.name.**
```

where `package.class.name` is the package name with the class name of the jar file appended.

For example:

```
-dontwarn com.myexternalclass.utils.**
```