# ProGuard configuration for Guava with obfuscation and optimization

Tags: java, android, guava, proguard

Looking for a ProGuard configuration for Guava that will obfuscate and optimize, as the default one that is provided on the website does not.

Not only that I cannot get it to export my apk, I keep getting:

```
Warning: com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue: 
    can't find referenced field 'int UNSET_EXPECTED_SIZE' in class  
    com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue$Builder
You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
```

Comment: This is more a Proguard question than anything else, I think?

Comment: More of a guava question actually. Something in Guava is causing that Class to throw a warning. The answer listed should resolve the issue.

Comment: Ah.  I was paying more attention to the first part of the issue: "a configuration that will obfuscate and optimize."

Comment: Yeah, two-part questions are quite annoying, but in this case, both parts are about proguard.

Answer (score 43):

As of **Guava 17.0**, this is what I needed in ProGuard config:

```
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.inject.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
```

Otherwise build fails with warnings like:

```
Warning: com.google.common.base.Absent: 
   can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
```

(That's because Guava uses annotations [that are not part of Android runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7003061/56285) (android.jar). In this case it's fine to just mute the warnings.)

If you are using [Gradle as the build tool](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide), the above `proguard-project.txt` and the following in `build.gradle` produces an optimised and obfuscated APK while using Guava.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile file('proguard-project.txt')
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
    }
}
```

---

**Alternatively** you can [include dependecy to jsr305.jar](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava) in `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.2'
```

...with only `-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe` in ProGuard config, but I preferred using `-dontwarn` also for the `javax` stuff.

Comment: By the way, if anyone is concerned about the effect of Guava dependency on **APK size**, don't be. [Simple testing showed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978699/#comment31438519_14979043) that without ProGuard Guava increases APK size by about 700KB, but with ProGuard the increase is negligible.

Comment: I'm using Guava `com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android` and your suggestion doesn't work on my proguard configuration. Any idea?

Answer (score 22):

I had to add the following lines to my proguard rules file when upgrading from 23.4-android to 23.5-android:

```
-dontwarn afu.org.checkerframework.**
-dontwarn org.checkerframework.**
```

The proguard warnings that I saw from the update (before adding new rules) are listed below for reference:

```
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.experimental.tainting_qual.qual.Untainted: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.experimental.tainting_qual.qual.Untainted: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.experimental.tainting_qual.qual.Untainted: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.experimental.tainting_qual.qual.Untainted: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.fenum.qual.FenumBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.fenum.qual.FenumBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.fenum.qual.FenumBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.formatter.qual.FormatBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.formatter.qual.FormatBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.formatter.qual.FormatBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.guieffect.qual.AlwaysSafe: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.guieffect.qual.AlwaysSafe: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.guieffect.qual.AlwaysSafe: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.i18n.qual.Localized: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.i18n.qual.Localized: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.i18n.qual.Localized: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.i18n.qual.Localized: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.i18n.qual.Localized: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.i18n.qual.Localized: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.i18n.qual.Localized: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.i18n.qual.Localized: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.i18nformatter.qual.I18nFormatBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.i18nformatter.qual.I18nFormatBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.i18nformatter.qual.I18nFormatBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.initialization.qual.FBCBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.initialization.qual.FBCBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.initialization.qual.FBCBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.framework.type.AnnotatedTypeMirror$AnnotatedPrimitiveType
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.framework.type.AnnotatedTypeMirror
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.LiteralTree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.framework.type.AnnotatedTypeMirror$AnnotatedPrimitiveType
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.KeyForBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.KeyForBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.KeyForBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.framework.type.AnnotatedTypeMirror$AnnotatedPrimitiveType
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.framework.type.AnnotatedTypeMirror
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.framework.type.AnnotatedTypeMirror$AnnotatedNoType
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.framework.type.AnnotatedTypeMirror$AnnotatedPrimitiveType
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.framework.type.AnnotatedTypeMirror$AnnotatedNoType
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.Mutable: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.Mutable: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.Mutable: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.Mutable: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.OIGJMutabilityBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.OIGJMutabilityBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.OIGJMutabilityBottom: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.framework.type.AnnotatedTypeMirror$AnnotatedPrimitiveType
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.OIGJMutabilityBottom: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.framework.type.AnnotatedTypeMirror
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.OIGJMutabilityBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.OIGJMutabilityBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.OIGJMutabilityBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.OIGJMutabilityBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.OIGJMutabilityBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.OIGJMutabilityBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.oigj.qual.OIGJMutabilityBottom: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.framework.type.AnnotatedTypeMirror$AnnotatedPrimitiveType
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.regex.classic.qual.RegexBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.regex.classic.qual.RegexBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.regex.classic.qual.RegexBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.signature.qual.SignatureBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.signature.qual.SignatureBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.signature.qual.SignatureBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.tainting.classic.qual.Untainted: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.tainting.classic.qual.Untainted: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.tainting.classic.qual.Untainted: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.tainting.classic.qual.Untainted: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.checker.units.qual.UnitsRelations: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.checker.units.UnitsRelations
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.common.aliasing.qual.MaybeAliased: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.common.aliasing.qual.MaybeAliased: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.common.aliasing.qual.MaybeAliased: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.common.reflection.qual.ClassValBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.common.reflection.qual.ClassValBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.common.reflection.qual.ClassValBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.common.reflection.qual.MethodValBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.common.reflection.qual.MethodValBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.common.reflection.qual.MethodValBottom: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.common.value.qual.BottomVal: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.common.value.qual.BottomVal: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.common.value.qual.BottomVal: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.framework.qual.ImplicitFor: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.framework.qual.ImplicitFor: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.framework.qual.ImplicitFor: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree$Kind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.framework.qual.ImplicitFor: can't find referenced class afu.com.sun.source.tree.Tree
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.framework.qual.ImplicitFor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: afu.org.checkerframework.framework.qual.ImplicitFor: can't find referenced class afu.org.checkerframework.framework.type.AnnotatedTypeMirror
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.lock.qual.GuardedBy: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.lock.qual.GuardedBy: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.lock.qual.GuardedBy: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.lock.qual.GuardedBy: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.lock.qual.GuardedBy: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.lock.qual.GuardedBy: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.lock.qual.GuardedBy: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.lock.qual.GuardedBy: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: org.checkerframework.checker.units.qual.UnitsRelations: can't find referenced class org.checkerframework.checker.units.UnitsRelations
Warning: org.checkerframework.framework.qual.ImplicitFor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
```

For those interested, the full ruleset I have for guava currently is:

```
# Guava (official)
## Not yet defined: follow https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2117
# Guava (unofficial)
## https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2926#issuecomment-325455128
## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120338/proguard-configuration-for-guava-with-obfuscation-and-optimization
-dontwarn com.google.common.base.**
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**
-dontwarn com.google.j2objc.annotations.**
-dontwarn java.lang.ClassValue
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
# Added for guava 23.5-android
-dontwarn afu.org.checkerframework.**
-dontwarn org.checkerframework.**
```

Comment: Do you also include jsr library in the dependencies section of build.gradle?

Comment: Thank you so much man, you save my day!

It works on "guava:24.0-android" too

Answer (score 21):

**Edit (2023.10.23):** Looks like Guava started including Proguard configurations in version [32.0.0](https://github.com/google/guava/releases/tag/v32.0.0) (related [commit](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/aeba1e1b2d7f34bc972c74c9eccb1b2826e88514))!

---

One of the engineers who built R8 (Stephan Herhut) listed the following rules for the latest Guava (`25.0-android`) in [this session from Google I/O 2018](https://youtu.be/x9T5EYE-QWQ?t=21m50s):

```
-dontwarn afu.org.checkerframework.**
-dontwarn org.checkerframework.**
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn java.lang.ClassValue
```

The video also includes a short explanation of the rules (first 3 are static analysis annotation frameworks, last 2 are unavailable classes on Android which are protected by runtime checks in Guava).

I spoke with Stephan after the session and he said these will hopefully be included in the Guava documentation in the future or better yet in the `consumerProguardFiles` of future Guava releases. Here's hoping!

Comment: Technically, Stephan's talk used Guava `24.1-android`, but I tested the rules with `25.0-android` and they worked.

Comment: Thanks for the groundbase explanation. Months passed and this is still not in guava's docs...

Comment: Looks like Guava finally started shipping Proguard configurations starting in https://github.com/google/guava/releases/tag/v32.0.0

Answer (score 18):

Now that [Guava 19.0 is released](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release19), I found that I had to add these rules.

```
-keep class com.google.j2objc.annotations.** { *; }
-dontwarn   com.google.j2objc.annotations.**
-keep class java.lang.ClassValue { *; }
-dontwarn   java.lang.ClassValue
-keep class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement { *; }
-dontwarn   org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
```

Comment: I'm using Guava `com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android` and your suggestion doesn't work on my proguard configuration. Any idea?

Answer (score 11):

For Guava 20.0 you need to add **also**:

```
# Guava 20.0
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.concurrent.LazyInit
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.ForOverride
```

Comment: I'm using Guava `com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android` and your suggestion doesn't work on my proguard configuration. Any idea?

Comment: @Eftekhari Make sure you added all the rules, i.e. not only for 22.0 but also fo 20.0, 19, etc. If that does not help: you can open a new question and paste the errors of your build

Answer (score 7):

[This message](http://groups.google.com/group/guava-discuss/msg/e51f9d9fd17867e9) suggests the following workaround:

```
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
```

I'd like to think that Proguard could be changed to make this unnecessary, but we haven't checked with its owners.

Answer (score 5):

Total proguard rule for guava 20.0. For now the latest [guava 21](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release21) does not support android.

```
-dontwarn com.google.common.base.**
-keep class com.google.common.base.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**
-keep class com.google.errorprone.annotations.** {*;}
-dontwarn   com.google.j2objc.annotations.**
-keep class com.google.j2objc.annotations.** { *; }
-dontwarn   java.lang.ClassValue
-keep class java.lang.ClassValue { *; }
-dontwarn   org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-keep class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement { *; }
```

Comment: [-keep are not needed](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2926#issuecomment-325456179).

Comment: missing
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.inject.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

Answer (score 4):

I just want to share what is actually working now for my app with the following in build.gradle:

> compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.5-android'

The following is in proguard-project.txt to deal with Guava.  It is essentially the combination of TimTron's answer and develper_7's tip:

```
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
-dontwarn com.google.common.util.concurrent.FuturesGetChecked**
-dontwarn javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
-dontwarn afu.org.checkerframework.**
-dontwarn org.checkerframework.**
```

Answer (score 3):

guava's jar files were produced by a java compiler that (unlike javac) kept extra references to private inlined constants in the constant pool of referencing classes in the same source file, which fails only with proguard 4.7, which appears to optimize away the private constant definitions, without optimizing away the references.  Future guava jar files will not have such constant pool references, but there's probably a bug in proguard 4.7 that does not manifest with jar files produced by standard javac.

Comment: ProGuard will optimize away the constant definition and reference fine, if you tell it to ignore the suspicious reference. In the compiled code, a class is referencing a private field in a different class. In my understanding, such a reference (without accessor methods) is not allowed (JVM specs 2.17.3). Other programs, like the JVM, may happen to be more forgiving due to lazy resolution. I'm still curious which compiler is producing this code.

Answer (score 3):

These proguard-rules worked for me: guava `23.3-android`

```
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
-dontwarn com.google.common.util.concurrent.FuturesGetChecked**
-dontwarn javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
```