# Ignore external libraries with Android proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I want to use Proguard mainly for obfuscation reasons.

I have a problem with proguard in Android. I used simpleframework to parse XML; its external.

In proguard cfg:

```
    -keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod    
    -keep public class org.simpleframework.**{ *; }
    -keep public class org.simpleframework.xml.**{ *; }
    -keep public class org.simpleframework.xml.core.**{ *; }
    -keep public class org.simpleframework.xml.util.**{ *; }
    -keep public class org.simpleframework.xml.stream.**{ *; }
    -keep public class javax.** { *; }
    -keep public class javax.xml.stream.**{ *; }

    -keep public class org.simpleframework.** {
      public void set*(***);
      public *** get*();
    }
```

error:

```
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Entry: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Entry: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Entry: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Entry: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Entry: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Entry: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.Location
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.Location
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.Location
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Start: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Text: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Text: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Characters
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Text: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Text: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Characters
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Text: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.Characters
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Text: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
Warning: org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader$Text: can't find referenced class javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent
```

I have no idea how to fix this problem. Path to gradle cfg is OK.

in gradle:

```
    buildTypes {
        release  {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile file('proguard.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proguard configuration help me: [Proguard obfuscation is breaking simplexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163250/proguard-obfuscation-is-breaking-simplexml/14458048#14458048)

```
# The following line may be different
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar(java/**,javax/**)

-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
# (3)Not remove unused code
-dontshrink

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
# (2)Simple XML
-keep public class org.simpleframework.**{ *; } 
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.**{ *; } 
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.core.**{ *; } 
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.util.**{ *; }
# (1)Annotations and signatures
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to eXistPierre post, this is the minimum I needed to get it working:

```
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar(java/**,javax/**)
-keep public class org.simpleframework.**{ *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.**{ *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.core.**{ *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.util.**{ *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
```

I also needed to add the following so I could read and write my class objects:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.package.app.ClassItem{ *; }
```

Comment: THIS WAS IT. I was desperate as I could not find any solution, and this was exactly what I needed to do! Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Those are not errors in the output but warnings that you can skip with :

```
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.xml.stream.**
```

or in general case :

```
-dontwarn
```

---

P.S. After skip I got

> Value is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.InstructionOffsetValue]

it was fixed with [adding the next line](http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/505/) to proguard

```
-optimizations !class/unboxing/enum
```