# Get error when the export android app that used proguard in it

Tags: android, proguard

I try to export my app.I fill the fields in the export apk file wizard When click on the finish button get errors   I use Proguard in my app Like this:

```
    proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=..\\..\\SlidingMenu-master\\library
android.library.reference.2=../appcompat_v7
```

I don't change the Proguard project file in my app.
Console errors:

```
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$1: can't find superclass or interface com.util.IabHelper$OnIabSetupFinishedListener
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$3: can't find superclass or interface com.util.IabHelper$OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$4: can't find superclass or interface com.util.IabHelper$QueryInventoryFinishedListener
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.OneJpegPerIframe: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.AboutUsActivity: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Help_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.AboutUsActivity: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Setting_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.AddCollectionActivity: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Setting_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.AddCollectionActivity: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Help_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.AudioRecorder: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Mp4ParserWrapper
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.AudioRecorder: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Mp4ParserWrapper
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Intent_values
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Intent_values
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper$OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper$OnIabSetupFinishedListener
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper$QueryInventoryFinishedListener
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper$OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper$QueryInventoryFinishedListener
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$1: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper$OnIabSetupFinishedListener
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$1: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$1: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$1: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$3: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper$OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$3: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$3: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$3: can't find referenced class com.util.Purchase
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$3: can't find referenced class com.util.Purchase
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$3: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$3: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$3: can't find referenced class com.util.Purchase
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$3: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$3: can't find referenced class com.util.Purchase
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$4: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper$QueryInventoryFinishedListener
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$4: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$4: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$4: can't find referenced class com.util.Inventory
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$4: can't find referenced class com.util.Inventory
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$4: can't find referenced class com.util.IabHelper
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$4: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$4: can't find referenced class com.util.Inventory
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$4: can't find referenced class com.util.IabResult
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.BuyPremiumActivity$4: can't find referenced class com.util.Inventory
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Collection_List_Activity: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Intent_values
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Collection_List_Activity: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Intent_values
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Collection_List_Activity: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Help_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Collection_List_Activity: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Setting_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Collection_List_Activity$2: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Subjects_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Collection_List_Activity$2: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Intent_values
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Collection_List_Activity$2: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Intent_values
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_Collection_Activity: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Setting_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_Collection_Activity: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Help_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$15: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$15: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$15: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$15: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$15: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$17: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$17: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$17: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$17: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$17: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$18: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$18: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$18: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity$18: can't find referenced class com.nabproduct.nabege.Edit_subject_Activity
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Warning: there were 81 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
[2015-10-16 11:45:37 - nabege] Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always add your Libraries in the `Don't Warn` zone in Progruard Rules File:

For Example:

```
-dontwarn YOUR_LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME.**
```

**Edit:**
You need to refrain your entire `Libraries` or pirticular `Classes` in your `Libraries` from Obfuscation. For doing that you can simple Follow this Link:

http://omgitsmgp.com/2013/09/09/a-conservative-guide-to-proguard-for-android/

You can also check this Question, which explains How to put Your `Library` in the `Don't Warn` Zone while refraing from it's Code Obfuscation.

[How to use -dontwarn in ProGuard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123835/how-to-use-dontwarn-in-proguard)

*Note:* If The entire code inside your Library is obfuscated then Your Application will surely have some runtime crashes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think this code don't let to SDK that run Proguard algorithm on the codes If  this is true ? How to use in my app

Comment: Ok, that's some how a valid point. Lemme create a prograud for your Libraries. I will update the answer soon.

Comment: Please check the updated answer, it will surely solve your problem.