# what is the difference between -keep class and -dontwarn

Tags: android, apk, proguard, android-proguard

Hey I'm new with proGuard , I use it to protect my code from reverse engineering , 
but when I built my signed apk I got a lot of errors when I enabled proGuard ,I have googled my problem I've found answers that says use -dontwarn for the classes that showing in the error message but after seeing the documentation from  proGuard  it says

> If you don't feel like filtering out the problematic classes, you can try your luck with the -ignorewarnings option, or even the -dontwarn option. **Only use these options if you really know what you're doing** though.

and I don't know what I'm doing 
and here is my `proguard-rules.pro` file

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn com.appodeal.**
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
```

and I've seen some answers says use `-keep class`

so can someone explain it

Comment: keep class means you are telling proGuard: Don't Touch this class, dontwarn means, whatever problems happen ... don't tell me :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`-keep class` Preserve the specified classes and class members.

`-dontwarn`
Don't warn about unresolved references at all.

More info here http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/refcard.html

Comment: Does it mean that it is safer to write ignore and following keep class for same class. for example: -dontwarn okio.** -keep class okio.**

Answer (score 6):

```
-dontwarn
```

Specifies not to warn about unresolved references and other important problems at all. The optional filter is a regular expression; ProGuard doesn't print warnings about classes with matching names. Ignoring warnings can be dangerous. For instance, if the unresolved classes or class members are indeed required for processing, the processed code will not function properly. Only use this option if you know what you're doing!

```
-keep class
```

Specifies classes and class members (fields and methods) to be preserved as entry points to your code. For example, in order to keep an application, you can specify the main class along with its main method. In order to process a library, you should specify all publicly accessible elements.

Hope this Helps!!