# Android app doesn't work after published it by generate signed app

Tags: android, android-emulator, signed, android-proguard

I create an app and it work on emulator. It works on debug apk on device, but when I build it with generate signed app it doesn't work?
what is wrong and how I can debug it on device on signed sate?

Comment: You ues ProGuard ? Check -dontwarns .

Comment: Yes I use ProGuard. what is -dontwarns?

Comment: see this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123835/how-to-use-dontwarn-in-proguard

Comment: Thanks, I add used dependency to build by -dontwarms, but problem didn't solved. How can find what dependency create the problem?

Comment: Can you tell me which type of functionlity  is not working

Comment: I don't know what is exactly but I think its related to encrypting or retrofit library!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project doesn't run signed app. I changed minifyEnabled value from true to false then problem is solve . this bad solution. I'm looking for a better way.

build.gradle :

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled false //true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
```

Comment: After disable minifyEnabled it's work properly, but I need it in my project

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and solved it.
I must keep models form obfuscating that use retrofit. After use below code my app work properly in minifyEnabled enabled:

-keep com.xxx.xxx.models.** { *; }

retrofit need to know class properties for filling by values.

Thanks every body try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found progard has problem with retrofit interfce

Sample of interface:

```
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;


public interface AClient {
    // For register device for specific package
    @GET("/api/initiate/{packageId}")
    Call<InitiateModel> GetInitiateInfo(
            @Path("packageId") int packageId
    );
  }
```

I add -dontwarn retrofit2.** in progard file.
What is wrong?