# after publishing my app to Google Play, App doesn't work

Tags: android, google-play

I made an app. It doesn't work after publishing to Google play.

I generated signed APK and i uploaded it, before uploading i tested release-apk 
on NOX-APP-Player, android Emulater, and my Phone.

But released apk worked perfectly. Same one, which i uploaded to Google play, didn't work. it only showed white screen..

I've spent 24 hours for solving this problem,, but i havent found proper solution.. Only thing i found is like proguard issues..
[Android app doesn't work after published it by generate signed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419854/android-app-doesnt-work-after-published-it-by-generate-signed-app)

but it didn't help ..

Somebody help me pleaseeeeeeeeee

my manifest file is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<!--
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />-->
<!--
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />-->

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.sauce.semo.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>


    <activity android:name="com.sauce.semo.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.sauce.semo.SearchActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <service
        android:name="com.sauce.semo.BubbleService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity android:name="com.sauce.semo.Alert_Dialog"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

</application>
```

also , i installed apk-release , i found this things..
is it related to my problem??

```
10-03 23:44:06.455 27822-27840/? V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found: 
                                                        MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIJAMLgh0ZkSjCNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMw
                                                        EQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29n
                                                        bGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5kcm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDAeFw0wODA4MjEyMzEz
                                                        MzRaFw0zNjAxMDcyMzEzMzRaMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYw
                                                        FAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5k
                                                        cm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDCCASAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggENADCCAQgCggEBAKtW
                                                        LgDYO6IIrgqWbxJOKdoR8qtW0I9Y4sypEwPpt1TTcvZApxsdyxMJZ2JORland2qSGT2y5b+3JKke
                                                        dxiLDmpHpDsz2WCbdxgxRczfey5YZnTJ4VZbH0xqWVW/8lGmPav5xVwnIiJS6HXk+BVKZF+JcWjA
                                                        sb/GEuq/eFdpuzSqeYTcfi6idkyugwfYwXFU1+5fZKUaRKYCwkkFQVfcAs1fXA5V+++FGfvjJ/Cx
                                                        URaSxaBvGdGDhfXE28LWuT9ozCl5xw4Yq5OGazvV24mZVSoOO0yZ31j7kYvtwYK6NeADwbSxDdJE
                                                        qO4k//0zOHKrUiGYXtqw/A0LFFtqoZKFjnkCAQOjgdkwgdYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/T
                                                        gt9r45jk14alMIGmBgNVHSMEgZ4wgZuAFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/Tgt9r45jk14aloXikdjB0MQswCQYD
                                                        VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIG
                                                        A1UEChMLR29vZ2xlIEluYy4xEDAOBgNVBAsTB0FuZHJvaWQxEDAOBgNVBAMTB0FuZHJvaWSCCQDC
                                                        4IdGZEowjTAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQBt0lLO74UwLDYKqs6Tm8/y
                                                        zKkEu116FmH4rkaymUIE0P9KaMftGlMexFlaYjzmB2OxZyl6euNXEsQH8gjwyxCUKRJNexBiGcCE
                                                        yj6z+a1fuHHvkiaai+KL8W1EyNmgjmyy8AW7P+LLlkR+ho5zEHatRbM/YAnqGcFh5iZBqpknHf1S
                                                        KMXFh4dd239FJ1jWYfbMDMy3NS5CTMQ2XFI1MvcyUTdZPErjQfTbQe3aDQsQcafEQPD+nqActifK
                                                        Z0Np0IS9L9kR/wbNvyz6ENwPiTrjV2KRkEjH78ZMcUQXg0L3BYHJ3lc69Vs5Ddf9uUGGMYldX3Wf
                                                        MBEmh/9iFBDAaTCK
```

10-03 23:44:06.460 27822-27822/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.sauce.semo time:102664802

Comment: Oh i just checked. When i run release apk(not from google play) on my device, sometimes it works but somtimes it didnt...

Comment: Did u check your version number and package name? not like example.com...?

Comment: @ibtehaz Thank you for comment, This is from my build.gradle

Comment: defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sauce.semo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 8
        versionName "0.7.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

Comment: Is it okay for My Master folder name is project20160929?

Comment: Would you post your manifest file on your questions (Where you have defined your application) and also, in what mobile your app tends to crash? @MWP.

Comment: @ibtehaz Sure, Actually it doesn't crash, just showing white screen..

Comment: Well, hard to tell.. since u have no error. U might try to check the error log in android studio using ur app from app store. If u plugin ur mobile, android studio will show all the logs generated from ur device in ur logcat.

Comment: @ibtehaz  Thank you very much for your answer..  anyway i just found something weired things in my log.. Im not sure it is related to my app problem  I will add to my question

Comment: Do you use Google Maps? Does the map fit all the screen?

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez no i don't use google maps, just admob and firebase

Comment: ok, but the problem can be the same, are you using the right API keys to connect the services?, usually are different to debug and release

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez nope,,, i don't use any api ,, ㅠ.ㅠ

Comment: Yes you are using some API, but doing a small research people say this is a bug, do you have all your tools up to date? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/3RnmRhBd7rg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333220/googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid-message-google-play-services-9-0-0

Comment: Thanks for all of you guys . I just found what is wrong.. I used    'while(cookies==null){}'  with AsyncTask which gets cookies from website for starting mainactivity after getting cookies. this was problem, I don't know why anyway