# Build fails with Proguard returning Error Code - 1

Tags: android, android-proguard, worklight-studio

> ```
> [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
> [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Note: there were 5021 duplicate class definitions.
> [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore extends or implements
> ```
>
> program class org.apache.http.client.CookieStore
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.RequestWrapper extends or implements
>   program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.RequestWrapper extends or implements
>   program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpRequest extends or implements program
>   class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse extends or implements
>   program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program
>   class org.apache.http.client.CookieStore
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program
>   class org.apache.http.client.CookieStore
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program
>   class org.apache.http.client.CookieStore
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program
>   class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program
>   class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program
>   class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program
>   class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.client.CookieStore
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer depends on program
>   class org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.io.SessionInputBuffer depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.LineParser depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.LineParser depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.LineParser depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.LineParser depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: library class org.apache.http.message.LineParser depends on program class
>   org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] Warning: there were 32 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid]          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid]          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
>       [2016-09-23 16:44:03 - myAppAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)

Comment: try to delete libraries that you have added in your libs folder & never used them.

Answer (score 0):

These are just warnings. Probably you can just ignore them with:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
```

which means:

Ignore warning connected with package `org.apache.http` and subpackages.

Comment: I given this -dontwarn for all warnings. but still the same error is happening. My one is consumer version of IBM MFP 7.1

Answer (score 0):

First, please get the latest versions of the libraries that you are using in your app.

Secondly use dontwarn property in your proguard file

eg,

```
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }
-dontwarn twitter4j.**
```

This was for skipping the warnings thrown by the twitter4j library.Same you can apply for the libraries you are using in your app.

For more refer :

[How to use -dontwarn in ProGuard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123835/how-to-use-dontwarn-in-proguard)

You can also try any of these commands

```
 -keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }   
    -dontwarn android.support.v4.**
    -dontwarn javax.activation.**
    -dontwarn javax.security.**
    -dontwarn java.awt.**
    -libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
    -keep class javax.** {*;}
    -keep class com.sun.** {*;}
    -keep class myjava.** {*;}
    -keep class org.apache.harmony.** {*;}
    -keep public class Mail {*;}        
    -dontshrink
```

of course with your library names

Comment: I am not using this packages. And I given this -dontwarn for all warnings. but still the same error is happening. My one is consumer edition of IBM MFP 7.1

Comment: Please check if you have any other proguard files in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Replace android sdk -> tools -> Proguard with newset proguard version. This will work fine