# proguard in android application

Tags: android, configuration, apk, proguard, obfuscation

I am using external libraries like foursquare api and ABS library in my application.

When i enable proguard before exporting the app i get the below mentioned Error in console.

> Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
>       Note: there were 3686 duplicate class definitions.
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
>       fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions$Builder
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions$Builder
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
>       fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
>       Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
>       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
>       Warning: there were 35 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
>       You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
>       java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>       at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
>       at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
>       at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
>       at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)

I understood that i have to mention the external libraries in Proguard properties file. How i should mention is the problem.

Please see my proguard file

```
-injars      bin/classes
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars E:/android/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity

-keep public class * extends android.app.Service

-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver


-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
public static int v(...);
public static int i(...);
public static int w(...);
public static int d(...);
public static int e(...);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [proguard hell - can't find referenced class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974231/proguard-hell-cant-find-referenced-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're exporting your Android application with the Android plugin, the plugin already specifies a standard configuration for you. This configuration includes the basic -keep options and all the necessary -injars and -outjars options (hence the note about duplicate class definitions). This means that your proguard-project.txt file can be empty to begin with; it should only contain any project-specific configuration.

The warnings explain that the Foursquare library refers to the AppEngine library and even to the servlet library, but these latter libraries are missing from your project. That's not a problem, since your app presumably works fine in debug mode, without these libraries, so you can tell ProGuard to ignore these issues:

```
-dontwarn fi.foyt.foursquare.**
```

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)